# Condition for analytic function to be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Suppose $A\subset \mathbb C$ is open and suppose $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb C$ is analytic. Let $B[a, R] \subset A$ be a closed ball of center $a$ and radius $R$. Let $f=u+iv$ where $u, v$ are real valued.  Suppose $\max u|B[a, R]=0$ $f(a)=0$. Then $f|B[a, R]=0$.

It's easy to see that if $u|B[a, R]=0$ then $f|B[a, R]=0$, but I only know that the maximum value of $u$ is $0$. I'm trying not to use the maximum principle for harmonic functions, but I can use the maximum module principle for analytic functions if needed.

Comment: Do you know the open mapping theorem (for holomorphic functions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ analytic around $z=a$, not identically zero and $f(a) = 0$.

It means that in the neighborhood of $z= a$ : $$f(z) = C (z-a)^n + \mathcal{O}(|z-a|^{n+1}), \qquad C \ne 0, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}^*$$ 
Hence, taking $z-a = \epsilon \,\overline{C}^{1/n}$ you get $$f(a+\epsilon \,\overline{C}^{1/n}) = \epsilon^n |C|^2 +  \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{n+1})$$ whose real part is $> 0$ when $\epsilon$ is small enough.

(the same argument works for proving the open mapping theorem, and the maximum modulus principle)